# Learning Ember.js- Persistence In Many To Many Relationships

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

To learn Ember.js I started writing a small bookmark application. I'm struggling with issues related to wrong data handling now.

**To Explain The Application**

- User can add label
- User can add links to selected labels
- A Label can have n links
- A Link can have n labels
- Show links by selecting the associated labels

**The Issue**
Link data is not writtern to the data store. Because of this, local updates to the links model due selection changes are overwritten. Also, implementing true persistence later wouldn't work.

**Narrowing down the issue**

In IndexRoute I initialize the model:

```
model: function(params) {
    return {
        labels: this.get("store").find("label"),
        // TODO: this is probably wrong.
        links: Ember.A()
    };
}
```

On the one side I fetch label data from the data store. On the other side I initialize link data with an empty ember array.

In my opinion this is the root of the malfunction but I don't know how to implement this properly.
I tried to replace this with bogus references to the storage adapter:

`this.get("store").find("label").filter("_")`

This is neither right nor does it work properly. Then it continues to the point where I then can't use the storage adapter to update records:

```
// TODO: this is probably wrong.
this.get("links").addObject({
    name: linkName,
    url: linkUrl,
    labels: this.selectedLabels
});
/*store.push("link", {
    name: newLink,
    url: linkUrl,
    labels: this.selectedLabels
});*/
```

And so on.

Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1751/edit

How to store link data properly so changing the local data of the controler won't break the application?

**Edit:**
I think I found my conceptual mistake with your advice. Does that mean that I always have to handle the local copy aswell?

```
var link = this.get("model");
link.deleteRecord();
link.save().then(function(link) {
    var indexController = this.get('controllers.index');
    indexController.get("links").removeObject(link);
});
```

In your example you used a promise to add the object to the controller. In this code sample the promise will never fulfill- therefore it only works without.

Also in the `LabelController` the remove method should also deletes associated links. If I use `deleteRecord` in the forEach loop it only deletes one label and then it somehow brings the loop to exit. Is this intentionally or have I made a mistake?

I have updated your JsBin.
http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1987/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your JSbin http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1975/

If you want to persist records you must create them in the store with **createRecord()** and then **save()** them. The new newLink function

```
    newLink: function() {
        var store = this.get("store"),
            linkName = this.get("linkName"),
            linkUrl = this.get("linkUrl"),
            links = this.get("links"),
            selectedLabels = this.get('selectedLabels');

        if(selectedLabels.get('length') > 0) {
            if(linkName.length > 0 && linkUrl.length > 0) {
              var newLink = store.createRecord('link',
                {
                    name: linkName,
                    url: linkUrl
                });
              selectedLabels.forEach(function(label){
                newLink.get('labels').addObject(label);
              });
              newLink.save().then(function(link){
                links.addObject(link);
              });
              this.set("linkName", "");
              this.set("linkUrl", "");
            }
        } else {
            alert("You have to select a label!");
        }
    },
```

For **deleting records** there are **problems using forEach** because **the result of a find to the store is a live array**. You can see this discussion in GitHub https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/772.
So your remove label function should be (note the use of **toArray()** to make a static copy of the live array)

```
    remove: function() {
        var indexController = this.get('controllers.index'),
            label = this.get('model'),
            linksPromise = this.get('store').find('link');

        linksPromise.then(function(links){
            links.toArray().forEach(function(link){
                var linkLabels = link.get('labels'),
                    linkLabelsIds = linkLabels.mapProperty('id');

                if(linkLabelsIds.contains(label.get("id"))) {
                    if(linkLabelsIds.get("length") == 1) {
                        console.log("delete link: "+link.get("name"));
                        indexController.get("links").removeObject(link);
                        link.deleteRecord();
                        link.save();
                    }
                }
            });

            label.deleteRecord();
            label.save();
        });
    }
```

Final note, don't forget to make a **save()** on the records after deleting them, jsBin here: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1989/

Comment: This could have driven me crazy :-) Hopefully others find this answer before spending hours to figure out that you can't remove items in a for each loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined your models?

```
App.Label = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    links: DS.hasMany('link')
});

App.Link = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string'),
    labels: DS.hasMany('label')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        this.store.find('label')
    }
});

App.LabelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:
        <!-- functions here -->
});

<script type='text/handlebars' data-template-name="index">
    {{#each label in model itemController='label'}}
        {{label.title}}
            {{#each link in label.links}}
                {{link.title}}
            {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. They are in the Jsbin. Is there anzthing wrong with them?

Comment: I've made a few modifications here: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1754/edit

Looks like you'll need to make a component for links and pass it whichever label is currently selected. For 
{{#each label in model}}
{{#each link in label.links}} //This will be sideloaded due to your hasMany relationship
{{link.url}}
{{/each}}
{{/each}}

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass in links and use {{#each link in model}}{{#each label in model.labels}}{{/each}}{{/each}}. The hasMany property will sideload the other model as a property of the parent.

Comment: If you just want to get your current implementation working, have links: this.store.find('link') for the 2nd object in the model.

Comment: Somehow the Jsbin is not working for me. I tried to get my current implementation working. If you change the model reference to  this.store.find('link') you first have to change all uses (previously addObject, then store-push) and so on. Then you get all links no matter for what you filter. This I solved with bogus filters mentioned in my question. However, it still didn't worked like it should and I couldn't begin to explain myself why.

Comment: It looks like its working for me, except that it doesn't save. 

Just a few quick tips:

You can use this.controllerFor('index') rather than this.get('controller.index');

You can use this.store.find rather than this.get('store').find

You're not accessing the models directly, you're using a buffer. You need to add and remove from the model directly and let the properties update automatically. You have the relationships setup, so in your {{#each label in model}} or in the controller, you can reference this.get('links') and it will be the model, where you can append and delete to the model.

Comment: For me you can't do anything with links. They don't show up if you select labels and, you can't add them. I'm trying to come up with a solution myself but I think I lack the necessary experience. Further help would be much appreciated.